# Coherent intervals in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, gaps-and-islands

Consider a simple Diary table:

```
 Date   Mood
 ----   ----
 1      Good
 2      Good
 3      Good
 4      Bad
 5      Bad
 6      Good
```

I am interested in the ***mood intervals***, so that I would get a result like:

```
 Mood   BeginDate   EndDate
 ----   ---------   -------
 Good   1           3
 Bad    4           5 
 Good   6           6
```

Is that possible in SQL without using iteration?

Comment: Almost nothing requires iteration in SQL. This type of problem is called the `gaps and islands` problem. You're trying to identify the ranges/islands that have the same `mood` value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you! That's the exact general problem, I was trying to solve by giving an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you subtracts a sequence number from the days that starts for each mood, you will get a constant when the values are adjacent:

```
 Date   Mood    Seqnum
 1      Good       1
 2      Good       2
 3      Good       3
 4      Bad        1
 5      Bad        2
 6      Good       4
```

Then you can use aggregation to do what you want.  If `date` is really a number:

```
select mood, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by mood order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by mood, (date - seqnum);
```

If `date` is really a `date`:

```
select mood, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by mood order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by mood, dateadd(day, - seqnum, date)
```

Comment: Clear answer. Thank you. As I understand it now, this is considered the general approach to the Gaps and Islands problem in SQL.

Comment: @Mal . . . There is no "general" approach.  There are a family of different solutions for different variants on the problem.  It is entirely a misconception that there is "1" gaps-and-islands problem.

Comment: Not sure this works at all. Try with test data which alternates two rows of Good with two rows of bad followed by two rows of good. In this case the seqnum has the sequence (1,2,1,2,3,4), and the difference becomes (0,0,2,2,2,2), giving just two coherent ranges

Answer (score 1):

In response to this comment in Gordon Linoff's answer:

> If `date` is really a number:

What if it's *not*? You still have a way forward, with one tiny tweak.

```
WITH d AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        (cast('2021-04-22 00:00' as datetime2(0)), 'Good'),
        (cast('2021-04-22 00:05' as datetime2(0)), 'Good'),
        (cast('2021-04-22 00:07' as datetime2(0)), 'Good'),
        (cast('2021-04-22 00:10' as datetime2(0)), 'Bad'),
        (cast('2021-04-22 00:25' as datetime2(0)), 'Bad'),
        (cast('2021-04-22 01:43' as datetime2(0)), 'Good')
    ) AS x([date], mood)        
), t AS (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [date]) AS a,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mood ORDER BY [date]) AS seqnum
    FROM d
)
select mood, min(date), max(date)
from t
group by mood, a - seqnum
order by min(date)
```

Breaking it down, the first cte is just your data, but now with a datetime column instead of an integer for `date`. Note, the intervals between successive rows is not constant (it can be, but I did it that way to show that it *needn't* be). From there, we're calculating two values with the `row_number()` function - one enumerates over the entire set and the other partitioned by mood.  The rest is the same (in spirit) as Gordon's answer.

Comment: I actually ended up doing exactly this in my real problem, but Gordon's answer helped me understand the solution and come to the same conclusion. Basically I needed to learn `PARTITION` and the associated observation, that adjacent rows have constant row number differences.

Comment: Sure. The above is intended to help others in the case where their data is not as neat as the sample data you presented. Cheers!